# How to stretch XAxis in MPAndroid chart to the edge of screen?

Tags: android, view, mpandroidchart

[image: Axis below Chart]

I want to stretch bottom axis to match width of screen in MPAndroid chart. Is there any way to do it?

[image: Glasswire]

And how **GlassWire** menages to build beautiful graph like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove offset in chart.

   ```
   chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
   ```
2. GlassWire

have to check what library used for GlassWire. I try to see in app, i can't see open source from app.
or you have to make custom view for MPChart

Comment: I did this as you told me but XAxis is now gone. I'm using Chart inside a horizontal recycle view.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The issue was that the bottom Axis was getting out of parent view when I set chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f); so I have to set it to chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 64f);